# Is a precise capacitor ratio repeatable?

Tags: analog, capacitance, tolerance

[image: RC divider schematic]

I have designed a 1 MΩ, 0-100 MHz fixed attenuator circuit (15 pF / 300 pF). I am using 1% C0G capacitors.  There is also a TS5A2053 analog switch connected to the output of the attenuator.  The switch will add 18.5 pF of capacitance to ground (typical).  I will layout the PCB to minimize stray capacitance and I will tune the values to that layout.

My question is, when this circuit is produced in volume, how much variation in the capacitance ratio should I expect to see from unit to unit? And what are the causes of this variation?

Obviously the capacitors (±1%) themselves will yield ±2%. The resistors' capacitance contribution is negligible.

C0G should not change much with age?  Would soldering change the value? How much variation should I expect from the analog switch (only "typical" is specified)?

To be specific, it is a simple voltage divider -- two resistors and two capacitors.

I have found several sources which say that the capacitance of a MOSFET does *not* vary with temperature. So, the capacitance of my analog switch will not likely vary with temp - I think only the switch's initial capacitance will vary due to process differences (thickness of the diffusion channel?).

Comment: Can you supply a circuit diagram.  You talk only about capacitors but then what does the 1Mohm refer to? Why is the effect of whatever resistors you have negligible? You can't get down to 0 Hz with only capacitors.  Are you trying to build something similar to an oscilloscope X10 probe?

Comment: The resistors are negligible because they have less than 0.1pf of capacitance. I have confidence that the resistance will be as expected.   Thus the question is only about the capacitance.   And, yes, the circuit is for the input of and instrument like application.  I am trying to avoid mechanical relays and manual adjustments.

Comment: Sometimes, if possible, it may be cheaper in production to duplicate the circuit that would receive the signal than to use a switch. It's not always possible of course, but just another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1% capacitors have a ratio accurate to +1.92/-1.89%.

Possible variation in the input capacitance of the switch is hard to estimate without more knowledge of the processes, a WAG might be 10-20% of the nominal value to 2-3 \$\sigma\$. At 20% it would be adding +/-1.2% to the error.

Maybe consider using a lower capacitance switch such as a USB switch- some of them are in the 7pF nominal range. You may also see some variation of the switch capacitance with voltage which could cause some distortion of the waveform.

Of course whatever you have on the other side of the switch is going to add to the capacitance etc.

Good C0G capacitors should have negligible voltage coefficient and should be very stable with temperature (< 30ppm/K) and time. Do check the detailed information (not just the data sheet) from your proposed supplier.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at USB switches; but I haven't found any in leaded packages that are also low cost.  BGAs and QFNs would greatly complicate assembly and at low volumes would increase my cost.

Answer (score 1):

A side issue about the schematic itself: you may find unacceptable ringing, or loading of the source, with the design as shown.  Obviously, the circuit approaches pure capacitance at high frequency; but a real circuit is never just that, but has stray inductance and resistance as well.

It is better to approach a constant resistance instead.  The topological change is simply to add resistors in series with the capacitors.  Their values will have the same ratio as the DC resistors.  The bottom resistor shall be dimensioned so that, in parallel combination with the load (after the switch), the desired output impedance is obtained (50Ω?).  This gives a matched source impedance into the load.  The top resistor is then set by ratio to that equivalent.  This much higher input impedance (1kΩ?) both loads the source less, and has less effect with respect to frequency (i.e. it's not reactive).

This gives an impedance curve which starts flat at DC (1M), drops starting from a (fairly low) breakpoint, looks capacitive for middle frequencies, then levels off at high frequencies (approaching a "low-Z probe" characteristic).

This is actually how oscilloscope probes are made -- this fact is not often enumerated in appnotes unfortunately; and is also only relevant at quite high frequencies, which might not've been of interest historically.  (And those historic references may get repeated without critical evaluation, and so on.)  Specifically for probes, the tip has some distributed capacitance with its resistance, giving the desired Z(F) curve; and the bottom impedance is formed by the cable, which is intentionally lossy (giving an overall transfer characteristic that matches).

As for manufacturing, if a trimming step is unacceptable, then the only recourse is either very precise capacitors ($$$), or if this is going into an ADC, perhaps a DSP filter curve can be programmed in during final testing?

Answer (score 0):

Without a schematic it is difficult to asses the problems your circuit could have.

Anyway, what I see as a potential problem, as far as both the repeatability *and* the precision is concerned, is the analog switch.

I doubt that the 18.5pF figure is specified to the same precision as your other parts (1%). Moreover, that capacitance may also drift sensibly with temperature (it's a semiconductor device) in an unknown way. That's why in many high-end instruments precision attenuators for low-level signals are often made with micro-relays.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I am trying to avoid mechanical switching and manual adjustments.